# Creating a new list when before it reaches a number

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do I create a new list that contains sublists of ints but the way of divide it is when the next number is the minimun (or equal to the first value founded)?

For example

```
List1=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The output that I am looking for is shown below:

```
Complete_List=[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

I tried looping through the list and appending it when the value is greater than 1 . However it will not work as it doesn't create another list inside it.

Do I have to right a regex for this problem?

Some guidance would be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: The problem description is unclear. Do you actually try to split your list into a list of lists of monotonically increasing numbers?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: That is correct. The number will always increase  from 1to certain number and goes back to 1. I need to split that into list of number ranging from 1 to that number so it would look like [[1....50[,[1.....23],[1.,,,12],[1...100],...] and so on

Comment: I suspect that the problem is only in the way you added your sub-list to the final list.  Gather the sequence of numbers, and `append` that sub-list to the master list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that will split a generic iterable on a given value.

```
def split_on_value(iterable, split_value):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    outer, inner = [], [next(iterator)]

    for value in iterator:
        if value == split_value:
            outer.append(inner)
            inner = []
        inner.append(value)

    outer.append(inner)
    return outer


value_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print split_on_value(value_list, 1)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

print split_on_value(value_list, 3)
# [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 1, 2], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you search for the 1's, or whatever your condition is, and get the indices within the list. Don't forget to append the `len(list)` to include the last segment.

```
idx = [i for i, l in enumerate(List1) if l == 1] + [len(List1)]
```

Optional, if you want the beginning end of the List. That is, you do not know if there will be a `1` always at index 0.

```
idx = [0] + idx if idx[0] != 0 else idx
```

Then, split the list at those indices you found.

```
complete_list = [List1[ind1:ind2] for ind1, ind2 in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:])]
```

and the result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla, straightforward, CS101 solution. Though, possibly the most efficient one, because it scans the list exactly once. It also does not assume that segments begin with 1.

```
fragment = []
result = []
prev = List1[0] - 1 # Preset the previous element marker

for n in List1:
  if n > prev:
    fragment.append(n)
  else:
    result.append(fragment)
    fragment = [n]
  prev = n

result.append(fragment)
#[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: I was just writting something like that, great job ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to split at every instance of 1:

```
List1=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6]

print [map(int, list("1"+i)) for i in ''.join(map(str, List1)).split("1")][1:]
```

By mapping over List1 with the string function, we can then join all the numbers in the list into one large string. From there, the algorithm splits itself at each instance of one, creating a list containing the new strings of digits. from there, the code maps the integer function over a list created of the strings and appending 1 at the front of the string to make up for the lost 1 when it originally split, creating a list within a list.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. I need to split at every instance of 1. However, Can you please explain how it creates the 1st list?

Comment: Actually, there is a problem with this solution if it goes above 9. If it goes above 9 it will be give [[1,2...,9],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 9. If the list is a sequence of [1, 2, 3, 4...9, 1...6], it still runs correctly for me. What sequence did you test?

Comment: Hi, I tested it on sequence [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]